# Why is this a heap buffer overflow when everything seems alright?

Tags: c++, security, buffer, overflow

When I'm using the Fuzzer and Adresssanitizer in clang and test against `memcpy`, both report a heap buffer overflow, but I cannot explain myself actually "Why". Within a dummy function named `foo`, I create a buffer named `buf` with the size of 4 bytes. The function foo accepts a parameter named `str` which, as the name suggests, should contain a string. In this example, I passed the string "hello" to foo. Since only 4 bytes fit into buf, I also instructed memcpy to always only copy 4 bytes from the parameter str, otherwise we'd overflow.

However, why does the Clang fuzzer/AdressSanitizer report a heap-overflow? To me everything seems fine... I copy from a larger string ("hello") only 4 bytes into a buffer (buf) which can hold only 4 bytes anyway..

To create the error, this is the source file `fuzz_string.cpp`:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>


int foo(const char *str)
{
    char    buf[4];

    memcpy(buf, str, sizeof(buf));

    return 0;
}


extern "C" int LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const uint8_t* data, size_t size)
{
    foo(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data));
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with:
`clang++ -g -fsanitize=address,fuzzer fuzz_string.cpp -o fuzz_string`

Also create a subdirectory named `corpus/` and place a file named `input1` within there containing:

```
hello
```

After that execute the program by running:
`./fuzz_string corpus -max_len=1000` which outputs:

```
./fuzz_string corpus -max_len=1000
INFO: Running with entropic power schedule (0xFF, 100).
INFO: Seed: 3852592942
INFO: Loaded 1 modules   (2 inline 8-bit counters): 2 [0x558e0d7deed0, 0x558e0d7deed2),
INFO: Loaded 1 PC tables (2 PCs): 2 [0x558e0d7deed8,0x558e0d7deef8),
INFO:        1 files found in corpus
=================================================================
==3433==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000011 at pc 0x558e0d79bf20 bp 0x7ffeb3a6b750 sp 0x7ffeb3a6b748
READ of size 1 at 0x602000000011 thread T0
    #0 0x558e0d79bf1f in foo(char const*) /mnt/c/Users/masch/Documents/Workbench/C/nexus-src/fuzz_string.cpp:19:14
    #1 0x558e0d79c160 in LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput /mnt/c/Users/masch/Documents/Workbench/C/nexus-src/fuzz_string.cpp:30:5
    #2 0x558e0d6c2323 in fuzzer::Fuzzer::ExecuteCallback(unsigned char const*, unsigned long) (/mnt/c/Users/masch/Documents/Workbench/C/nexus-src/fuzz_string+0x3e323) (BuildId: b5f5fad80b257a1e799c54575adef93091b807c4)
    #3 0x558e0d6c3580 in fuzzer::Fuzzer::ReadAndExecuteSeedCorpora(std::vector<fuzzer::SizedFile, std::allocator<fuzzer::SizedFile> >&) (/mnt/c/Users/masch/Documents/Workbench/C/nexus-src/fuzz_string+0x3f580) (BuildId: b5f5fad80b257a1e799c54575adef93091b807c4)
    #4 0x558e0d6c3bd2 in fuzzer::Fuzzer::Loop(std::vector<fuzzer::SizedFile, std::allocator<fuzzer::SizedFile> >&) (/mnt/c/Users/masch/Documents/Workbench/C/nexus-src/fuzz_string+0x3fbd2) (BuildId: b5f5fad80b257a1e799c54575adef93091b807c4)
    #5 0x558e0d6b1f22 in fuzzer::FuzzerDriver(int*, char***, int (*)(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)) (/mnt/c/Users/masch/Documents/Workbench/C/nexus-src/fuzz_string+0x2df22) (BuildId: b5f5fad80b257a1e799c54575adef93091b807c4)
    #6 0x558e0d6dbc12 in main (/mnt/c/Users/masch/Documents/Workbench/C/nexus-src/fuzz_string+0x57c12) (BuildId: b5f5fad80b257a1e799c54575adef93091b807c4)
    #7 0x7ff7481b6d8f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29d8f) (BuildId: 203de0ae33b53fee1578b117cb4123e85d0534f0)
    #8 0x7ff7481b6e3f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29e3f) (BuildId: 203de0ae33b53fee1578b117cb4123e85d0534f0)
    #9 0x558e0d6a6964 in _start (/mnt/c/Users/masch/Documents/Workbench/C/nexus-src/fuzz_string+0x22964) (BuildId: b5f5fad80b257a1e799c54575adef93091b807c4)

0x602000000011 is located 0 bytes to the right of 1-byte region [0x602000000010,0x602000000011)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x558e0d79985d in operator new[](unsigned long) (/mnt/c/Users/masch/Documents/Workbench/C/nexus-src/fuzz_string+0x11585d) (BuildId: b5f5fad80b257a1e799c54575adef93091b807c4)
    #1 0x558e0d6c2232 in fuzzer::Fuzzer::ExecuteCallback(unsigned char const*, unsigned long) (/mnt/c/Users/masch/Documents/Workbench/C/nexus-src/fuzz_string+0x3e232) (BuildId: b5f5fad80b257a1e799c54575adef93091b807c4)
    #2 0x558e0d6c3580 in fuzzer::Fuzzer::ReadAndExecuteSeedCorpora(std::vector<fuzzer::SizedFile, std::allocator<fuzzer::SizedFile> >&) (/mnt/c/Users/masch/Documents/Workbench/C/nexus-src/fuzz_string+0x3f580) (BuildId: b5f5fad80b257a1e799c54575adef93091b807c4)
    #3 0x558e0d6c3bd2 in fuzzer::Fuzzer::Loop(std::vector<fuzzer::SizedFile, std::allocator<fuzzer::SizedFile> >&) (/mnt/c/Users/masch/Documents/Workbench/C/nexus-src/fuzz_string+0x3fbd2) (BuildId: b5f5fad80b257a1e799c54575adef93091b807c4)
    #4 0x558e0d6b1f22 in fuzzer::FuzzerDriver(int*, char***, int (*)(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)) (/mnt/c/Users/masch/Documents/Workbench/C/nexus-src/fuzz_string+0x2df22) (BuildId: b5f5fad80b257a1e799c54575adef93091b807c4)
    #5 0x558e0d6dbc12 in main (/mnt/c/Users/masch/Documents/Workbench/C/nexus-src/fuzz_string+0x57c12) (BuildId: b5f5fad80b257a1e799c54575adef93091b807c4)
    #6 0x7ff7481b6d8f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29d8f) (BuildId: 203de0ae33b53fee1578b117cb4123e85d0534f0)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow /mnt/c/Users/masch/Documents/Workbench/C/nexus-src/fuzz_string.cpp:19:14 in foo(char const*)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c047fff7fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c047fff8000: fa fa[01]fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8010: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
==3433==ABORTING
MS: 0 ; base unit: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000


artifact_prefix='./'; Test unit written to ./crash-da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
Base64:
```

I tried googling for examples or explanations but unfortunately, none could help me out. This [link](https://aviii.hashnode.dev/the-art-of-fuzzing-a-step-by-step-guide-to-coverage-guided-fuzzing-with-libfuzzer) made me curious about this topic, but could not explain properly why this is causing a heap overflow when we copy only 4-bytes into a 4-byte destination.

Comment: Please update your question to include a [mcve] with a compilable piece of code as well as the command used to test and the exact output it gives.

Comment: Has been added! Execuse my mistake.

Comment: Please show how you're calling `LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput()`.

Comment: I wonder if `1-byte region` means something relevant. (you seem to be reading 4 bytes from an argument pointing to a 1-byte-long thing)

Comment: @Barmar, you can find more information about where it is being called here: https://llvm.org/docs/LibFuzzer.html.  TLDR; The libFuzzer library implements the `main()` and the fuzzer engine calls `LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput()` by default.

Comment: It will overflow if `strlen(str) < 3`.  Try: `memcpy(buf, str, strlen(str) < 3 ? strtlen(str) + 1 : sizeof(buf));` if you must use `memcpy()`.

Comment: Also, this is C++ and not C code.  Remove the C tag.

Comment: This only happens when the function is called from LibFuzzer? I suspect it's not calling the function as you assume.

Comment: The compiler can't guarantee that the size of the `str` parameter of `foo()` is 4 bytes.

Comment: Still happens, same error with Mr. Winds approach and @teapot418s suggestion. The error disappears when I'm trying something like `memcpy(buf, str, 1);`

Comment: `printf("%zu", strlen(s));`.  With 2 it will overflow for "".  If `str` can be null check that, too.

Comment: All the more reason to think that what you're copying from is smaller than you expect.  Which, by the way, is something that you need to protect against regardless, as best you can.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant `memcpy(buf, str, 1)` - copying one byte works somehow.

@JohnBollinger Interesting! I wish I'd understand more about this topic. Kind of hard to see trough this

Comment: Could it be, that since `LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const uint8_t* data)` accepts an `uint8_t *` as argument, the Fuzzer passes me only the letter `h`? Thus we succeed copying only a single byte but not 2, 3, or 4? It seems like it could be the only explanation... The uint8_t cannot hold anything larger than a pointer to a single byte.

Comment: Edit: When changing `foo(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data));` in LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const uint8_t* data)` to `foo("hello")` memcpy works as expected with no memory overflow. Awesome! The fault took `uint8_t *data`.

Comment: From your link: "Some important things to remember about fuzz targets:  The fuzzing engine will execute the fuzz target many times with different inputs in the same process. 
    **It must tolerate any kind of input (empty, huge, malformed, etc).**
". As others have pointed out, your function doesn't do that. It is not tolerant of too short input or null pointer input. Your function is not robust against calls that do not meet certain preconditions - which is what this testing is checking.

Comment: "a" would be too short input. See @AllanWind's comment.

Comment: Thanks alot Avi! I understand it now, great to have this forum it helped me out alot! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ prefer using a `std::string` or `std::vector` instead of `char *`.

In C (as it was tagged initially) if `str` is a string (`'\0'` terminated) then you code will overflow `str` if `strlen(str) < 3`.  I suggest you use `strncpy()` and ensure it's `'\0'` terminated:

```
int foo(const char *str) {
    if(!str) return !0; // ?
    char buf[4];
    strncpy(buf, str, sizeof buf - 1);
    buf[sizeof buf - 1] = '\0';
    return 0;
}
```

Or use `memcpy()` and ensure it's *not* `'\0'` terminated.  You need to keep `n` around to subsequently use the byte array:

```
size_t n = strlen(str) < sizeof buf ? strlen(str) : sizeof buf;
memcpy(buf, str, n);
```

If `str` is not a string then you cannot fix this in `foo()`.  I noticed how caller have a `size_t` which to me hint of a `char` array (and not a string).

Comment: The error occurs equally. It seems more likely that `LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const uint8_t* data, size_t size)` is the cause, `uint8_t *data` to be explicit. The pointer passed can only point to a single byte, thus explaining why copying 1-byte only succeeds instead of 2, 3, or 4 which generate the error report.

Comment: Yes, that is why I explicitly pointed out that you out of luck if the input is not a string.  Single byte is not a string unless it's "" aka `{'\0'}`,

Comment: Thanks alot! Problem found. The thread can be closed.

Comment: Is there a reason why this code is ignoring the `size` parameter of `LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput()`? Presumably that contains the actual size of the `data` being passed in.